# Facebook share button manifest provider android

Tags: android, facebook, android-manifest, facebook-share

I want to use facebook share button in my android app and I have encountered a problem with my manifest.
Since I am using multiple flavours for my app, I don't want to have an APP ID hardcoded in my manifest.
Facebook wants me to use this code in my manifest:

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{APP_ID}"
      android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
      android:exported="true"/>
```

Is it possible to use some kind of string resource to replace this APP ID?
I would like to do something like this:

```
<provider android:authorities="@string/facebook_provider_app"
      android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
      android:exported="true"/>
```

All help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you are using multiple flavors then You can create multiple manifests in your respective flavor's src folder.

Simply follow the instruction provided here [Add additional source directories for each flavour](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants)

Comment: I know you can add seperate manifest but these seems like a bit much for only 1 line of code...